# stopping Android Accessibility UI Component on softKey "HOME" Button pressed

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

Created  "AccessibilityService" and am able to show Hints based on the Text Entered.The Problem is i want to stop the activity service when the Host application Home Pressed.
I have tried Adding

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask|typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused"
                      android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
                    android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
                     android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description" />
```

With this am able to solve issue with phones which has Physical Button For "HOME".
How to Stop the Accessibility service When "HOME" event for Soft Buttons Like Nexus 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ANSWER TO ORIGINAL QUESTION: "Detecting when the software 'Home' button is pressed?"

As per Android documentation, Soft keyboards are not required to send hardware keyboard events and in fact the Android samples don't, so pretty much every software keyboard on the app store does not. You can only rely on the events from external Bluetooth and hardware keyboards.

Simply put, you can't reliably do what you want, the APIs don't support it.

ANSWER TO QUESTION EDIT:

Let me reiterate, THERE IS NO "RELIABLE" WAY TO DO THIS.

What you could do is listen for Screen change related events, and detect when the screen content matches the Home screen.  Now, this is still going to be a very fragile solution.  There is no consistent way to detect the Launcher Activity, vs any other Activity, and also no way to determine if perhaps the matcher you set up might match something that's not a Launcher Activity.  But, here is what I think to be the most reasonable approach.

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) {

    switch (e.getEventType()) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED: {
            if (detectHomeScreen(getRootInActiveWindow()) {
                //We are now at the "home" screen, do what you want here.
            }    
        }
    }
}
//A List of package names you know to be associated with "launcher" activities.  Populate this list in your classes static initialization block.
private static ArrayList<String> LAUNCHER_PACKAGE_NAMES;

private static boolean detectHomeScreen(AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNodeInfo) {
    return LAUNCHER_PACKAGE_NAMES.contains(rootNodeInfo.getPackageName().toString())
}
```

XML Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.SettingsActivity"
    />
```

The last one is cool.  It allows you to set an Activity that will open up via the "Settings" button in the top right corner of the Accessibility Service configuration screen.

Comment: I understand that i cannot expect the key events from softbutton implementation ,am seeing for a work around for to stop my accesibility service cause its shows a ui with relavant emoji's  on screen they dont make sense without a host application

Comment: Then you should word your question in a "functionality centric way".  Responding to a home button press can answer MANY different functional requirements.  Answers shoudn't have to speculate about what functional requirement you're answering with this mechanism.  Explain the behavior you want, not your broken solution.  If your requirement is "listen for home button to be pressed" you cannot.  That is the only specific question I see in your post.  If you say "I'm attempting to use this mechanism to do...." then perhaps I can help.

Comment: This being said, I recommend doing this in a different post.  The specific question you made "Can I listen for the home button to be pressed" has been answered, and that you CANNOT is useful information.  You should open up a new question saying "I want my accessibilityservice to behave like this... how can this happen?"  These two questions are separate, and uniquely useful.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for the Feedback , I have Edited my question as per for your feedback.Hope it has clearly states what am looking for

Comment: If an Edit to a question invalidates a reasonable answer, you should consider accepting the answer and asking a different question.  It is common for people to attempt similar things and follow similar lines of logic.  The fact that your solution DID NOT WORK for particular reasons is in itself helpful information.

Comment: Chris..What we noticied is onAccessibilityEvent is not Called at all when we Press "HOME" & "Back"

Comment: That is not accurate, you have a configuration issue, OR you're pressing them "Home" button when you're already on the Home screen.  Those sets of events fire on EVERY window update.  What's in your service_config xml file?

Comment: I have already put it in my question and i tried adding "flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows" But havent received any Soft "HOME" events

Comment: You're at the very least missing this:     android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"

Comment: Ahh, I see, you're using "typeAllMasked" mixed with other types.  This is nonsensical.  Android will ignore it.  What you've done is basically said 1111 & (1000 | 0100)... which DOES NOT equal 1111, it equals 1100.  I would leave type all masked alone, and then filter in the onAccessibilityEvent method.

Comment: You'll probably also want a notificationTimeOut.  I'll add my recommended configuration to the answer.

Comment: I tried the same configuration still the "onAccessibilityEvent" not called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140087/discussion-between-chriscm-and-surya).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i had to Listen to HomeWatch Listener with the following code.
https://gist.github.com/nfeld9807/0ab8341133c58c71f874

I was able to get the HOME Events.even though it took four days to figure out a way out.
Chris had Really helped me to think in proper direction.

Comment: WARNING: You're yet again relying on a fragile bit of implementation.  The reason this works is because "ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" is an intent that happens to get fired.  This is a public API.  But, the system Home button would not be required to use this method to close system dialogues.  So any launcher that does not, would break this method entirely.  My method is more reliable as it is it least PLAUSIBLE that it works on every system.  If it doesn't work you're missing a package name.  If this doesn't work for a particular system, YOU'RE HOSED.

Comment: Yeah ..this would probably work only for stock binary devices, but i tried approaches supposed to work not working,so for now i may i have to stick to this solution