# AccessibilityService setServiceInfo method's changes don't seem to take effect outside onServiceConnected

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

Quoting the docs for setServiceInfo 
"You can call this method any time but the info will be picked up after the system has bound to this service and when this method is called thereafter."

Accessibility has been enabled for my app and I have set the serviceInfo inside the onServiceConnected method and I am receiving events for those apps and all is well.

Now ,the problem is I'm trying to modify the package list by calling setServiceInfo outside the onServiceConnected method, but the changes are not taking effect( i.e i'm still receiving events from the packages in the package list specified earlier which are absent in the modified package list).

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo accessibilityServiceInfo = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    accessibilityServiceInfo.packageNames = new String[]{"packageA","packageB"};
    accessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED
            | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED
            | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED
            | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;
    accessibilityServiceInfo.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    accessibilityServiceInfo.notificationTimeout = 100;
    accessibilityServiceInfo.flags = (AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS | accessibilityServiceInfo.flags);
    setServiceInfo(accessibilityServiceInfo);
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent event) {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo serviceInfo = getServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.packageNames = new String[]{"packageA"};
    setServiceInfo(serviceInfo);
}
```

accessibility_service_config.xml

```
<accessibility-service 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
/>
```

So, the question is how do I add/remove packages inside the Accessibility Service depending on the Accessibility events I receive later?

Answer (score 2):

You can't exclude package names by adding them to that list.

```
serviceInfo.packageNames = null
```

Get events for all packages.

```
serviceInfo.packageNames = {"some.package"}
```

Get events ONLY for some.package.  This list is not exclusions, it's a list of things to only include.

Now, if you could keep a list of all packages that you want to get events for, you could do this. Setting service info dynamically is just dandy! But, TBH, you're making this way too difficult and not using this API the way its intended. If you want to exclude only a few things, it is very ill advised to save a list of every other package name in the world, to get their events. It seems to me like you need your own logic filter package names. I would try this instead:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) {

    //Do the filtering yourself.
    ArrayList<String> includedPackageNames = youlist;

    if (!includedPackageNames.contains(e.getPackageName())) return;

    //Do the rest of your stuff here.
}
```

EDIT:

You have some issues with your service info stuff. When you do this line:

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo accessibilityServiceInfo = new AccessibilityServiceInfo(); //This one!
    ...
}
```

You overwrite all of the information in your service_config.xml file as well as any default values that you DID NOT set in there. You should let service_config.xml handle your static initialization and only make dynamic changes by modifying the fetched serviceInfo object. OR, at the very least, fetch the one that has been built from your service config.

Change that line to this:

```
//Get the object that has been initialized with settings from your service_config.xml file
AccessibilityServiceInfo accessibilityServiceInfo = getServiceInfo();
```

OR, better yet, delete your entire onServiceConnected function, and do it all statically in your `service_config.xml` file.

Comment: Perhaps I was not very clear when I said "exclude".Let me explain.Initially I want to receive events for two packages "packageA" and "packageB" which  i set using setServiceInfo in onServiceConnected. Later after I receive a certain event I want to "exclude" packageB and just want events from packageA. Now I modify the packageNames array to contain just packageA and call setServiceInfo again, but I still receive events from packageB.I am currently using the way u suggested, but I figured why even bother receiving the event from packageB and return if I can unsubscribe PackageB.

Comment: Edited the question to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: You're going to all of this trouble to remove ONE "if" statement from your code? So, there is nothing wrong with your code that you've presented. It all should hypothetically work, so there's either a bug somewhere else in your code, or in Android. I'd be interested to see the code you ommitted by commenting and hand waving around initializing your service info initially. That said, this is definitely a non-standard use of this API, so don't discount the fact that you may have found a bug in Android.

Comment: The part of the code I commented out works absolutely fine. i.e I'm receiving events from both the packages like I'm supposed to. So, I saw no point in including the part which works.Would be happy to share it if it helps though.Coming to the one "if" statement, It is not so much about the lines of the code as much about the number of unnecessary events I keep receiving which'll do nothing but drain the battery when someone uses the package I'm not interested in anymore.

Comment: Include it. The lines of code you have that set the new service info are fine, so the issue is elsewhere. How you're building it initially would be interesting, and I'm also curious how you're launching your service.

Comment: Note: TalkBack receives events for most event types, constantly, from ALL packages, and barely shows up in the list of apps effecting my battery life. Just by limiting to your two packages you have optimized a TON on this scenario. This to me, seems like an unnecessary micro-optimization. Though, I'm still academically interested!!!

Comment: Included.I limited it to two packages for the sake of convenience.I have around 100 packages listed.I'll try and give a little more context. I'm trying to  detect the Home button press by listening to the launcher activity like you suggested [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43158274/5551621). But, once I know the user pressed home, I have no further use for events from the launcher activity, so I want to "exclude" it. Since the package in question is the launcher activity, I was afraid I'll drain the battery listening to events like scrolling in menu.

Comment: Do you still think it isn't worth the optimization considering the package being the launcher package and that I'd be receiving a lot of events when user navigates through the menu? Also, when you asked about how I was launching the service, did you mean the config.xml file?

Comment: Sending events back and forth does not cost an abundance of battery. TalkBack shows up on the list of "battery hogging" apps because it runs on top of EVERYTHING, all the time, cuz it's an Accessibility Service.  So, yeah, I definitely think what you're talking about is a super micro-optimization, and not worth it.

Comment: As for your service_config.xml. See my updates to the answer.

Comment: I changed it to use getServiceInfo like you asked to, but sadly the setServiceInfo method still shows no difference outside onServiceConnected. Nevertheless, the information about building service info and battery drain was very useful.Thanks for that.I'm upvoting the answer, but the answer to setting service Info dynamically still remains unanswered(possibly a bug like you said).

Comment: If I get time to dig into the relevant AOSP code I will and post a bug/pull request and confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same issue recently. After looking into source code (SDK 8.1), it seems the API description gives the wrong expectation that set packageNames to some app list then set it null would make the service receive all events again.

The reason is in two methods below. In #1 when you it calls setServiceInfo(info) where the info.mPackageNames is null, here it just skips it and never set service.mPackageNames to null. In #2, when mPackageNames already includes the apps you added before. So later mPackageNames.isEmpty() will always be false.

http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/services/accessibility/java/com/android/server/accessibility/AccessibilityManagerService.java#mPackageNames

## 1

line 2786 - 2788

```
if (packageNames != null) {
      mPackageNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(packageNames));
}
```

## 2

```
1428 Set<String> packageNames = service.mPackageNames;
1429        String packageName = (event.getPackageName() != null)
1430                ? event.getPackageName().toString() : null;
1431
1432        return (packageNames.isEmpty() || packageNames.contains(packageName));
```